# Nested classes in Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a config data from a DHCP server that I put into classes like this:

```
public class DHCP
{
    public DHCP()
    {
        this.Scopes = new List<Scope>();
    }

    public List<Scope> Scopes;

    public class Scope
    {
        public Scope(string ScopeAddress, string SubnetMask, string State, string ScopeName, string Comment)
        {
            this.ScopeAddress = ScopeAddress;
            this.SubnetMask = SubnetMask;
            this.State = State;
            this.ScopeName = ScopeName;
            this.Comment = Comment;
        }

        public Scope(string ScopeAddress, string SubnetMask, string State, string ScopeName, string Comment, bool initClients)
        {
            this.ScopeAddress = ScopeAddress;
            this.SubnetMask = SubnetMask;
            this.State = State;
            this.ScopeName = ScopeName;
            this.Comment = Comment;

            if (initClients)
                this.Clients = new List<Client>();
        }

        public void InitClients()
        {
            this.Clients = new List<Client>();
        }

        public void InitReservations()
        {
            this.Reservations = new List<Reservation>();
        }

        public string ScopeAddress { get; set; }
        public string SubnetMask { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ScopeName { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public List<Client> Clients;
        public List<Reservation> Reservations;
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public Client(string IPAddress, string SubnetMask, string UniqueID, string LeaseExpires, string ClientType)
        {
            this.IPAddress = IPAddress;
            this.SubnetMask = SubnetMask;
            this.UniqueID = UniqueID;
            this.LeaseExpires = LeaseExpires;
            this.ClientType = ClientType;
        }

        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        public string SubnetMask { get; set; }
        public string UniqueID { get; set; }
        public string LeaseExpires { get; set; }
        public string ClientType { get; set; }
        public Reservation ClientReservation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Reservation
    {
        public Reservation(string IPAddress, string UniqueID, bool ReservationActive)
        {
            this.IPAddress = IPAddress;
            this.UniqueID = UniqueID;
            this.ReservationActive = ReservationActive;
        }

        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        public string UniqueID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool ReservationActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I have a `List<DHCP.Client>` that I use for `DataSource` on the gridview. When I set one of the data fields to `ClientReservation.ReservationActive` I get a not found error.

I have tried this with a List<> where this is no NULL data at all.
So I have to questions:

Can this be done at all?
If I have an object where `Client.ClientReservation == null` how can I handle that on `DataBind()` without an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for both issues. By using a template field like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClientReservation.ReservationActive")%>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

It get's the value of the nested class (sub property) and ignores it without error if ClientReservation is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that as you can see you assign to all the property a value in the constructor except `ReservationActive`. Infact it remains null and this is why you get the error. So you should do:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(string IPAddress, string SubnetMask, string UniqueID, string LeaseExpires, string ClientType, Reservation ClientReservation)
    {
        this.IPAddress = IPAddress;
        this.SubnetMask = SubnetMask;
        this.UniqueID = UniqueID;
        this.LeaseExpires = LeaseExpires;
        this.ClientType = ClientType;
        this.ClientReservation = ClientReservation;
    }

    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string SubnetMask { get; set; }
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
    public string LeaseExpires { get; set; }
    public string ClientType { get; set; }
    public Reservation ClientReservation { get; set; }
}
```

And a pass **non-null value**. 
Else you can initialize it in this way without pass it through the constructor:

```
Client client = new Client();
client.ClientReservation = new Reservation("127.0.0.1", "ID", true); //example
```

Then you can use `myClient.ClientReservation` without get any error.

**EDIT:**

Another suggestion. Because you need to add some `Client`s. You could implement this possibility in this way:

```
public Scope
{
    //...
    public void AddClient(string IPAddress, string SubnetMask, string UniqueID, string LeaseExpires, string ClientType, Reservation ClientReservation){
        Clients.Add(new Client(IPAddress, SubnetMask, UniqueID, LeaseExpires, ClientType, ClientReservation));
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Scopes = new List<Scope>();
Scope scope = new Scope(/*...*/);
scope.AddClient(new Client(/*...*/)); 
Scopes.Add(scope);
```

Comment: Yes I can use myClient.ClientReservation in code but not as a bound field in the GridView control. That's my biggest problem right now.